# Range Facet on integer field in Lucene

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

So as the title says, I want to have range facets on integer fields.

In the documentation it says: ***Range faceting `LongRangeFacetCounts`, `DoubleRangeFacetCounts` compute counts for a dynamic numeric range from a provided `LongValuesSource`*** 
I can use LongRanceFacetCounts or DoubleRangeFacetCounts for any numeric type: `double`, `decimal`, `long`, `float`, but not `int`, which is annoying.

Does anybody have experience with getting a range facet from an int field?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can get a LongValuesSource for an int-valued field: [LongValuesSource.fromIntField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/LongValuesSource.html#fromIntField-java.lang.String-)

(Or, if you wish, a DoubleValuesSource:  [DoubleValuesSource.fromIntField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/DoubleValuesSource.html#fromIntField-java.lang.String-))

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I am using Lucene.net, and there doesn't appear to be a similar method. But your comment helped me found a solution.

Comment: In Lucene.NET, numeric types follow the .NET numeric naming conventions. Therefore, it would be `Int64ValueSource.FromInt32Field()` and `DoubleValueSource.FromInt32Field()`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @femtoRgon's comment, I found a solution for `Lucene.net`.

The DoubleRangeFacetCounts has a constructor like this:

`DoubleRangeFacetCounts(string field, **ValueSource valueSource,** FacetsCollector hits, params DoubleRange[] ranges)`

The `valueSource` param is interesting here, because we can pass different implementation of the class.

Fx.: `new Int32FieldSource(definitionFacet.Key)` if the field is an int
or `new DoubleFieldSource(definitionFacet.Key)` if the field is a double etc.

In hindsight it is obvious, but I didn't notice it at first